# Inject view in fragment with AndroidAnnotations

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-annotations

I'm trying to switch my fragments from classic implementation to AndroidAnnotations.
When I use @EFragment(R.layout.my_fragment) I get a blank view.

```
@EFragment(R.layout.my_fragment)
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
}
```

If I go like this it's ok :

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

What am I missing? The documentation says to add an underscore when I instanciate the fragment like :

```
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment_();
```

instead of :

```
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
```

But as I expected this is just giving a compilation error.

Comment: Did you check that the file `MyFragment_` was generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem which was very simple :

After adding AndroidAnnotations to my fragment, I simply forgot to update the import of it in my Activty. It needed to change from:

```
import com.project.ui.fragment.MyFragment;
```

to:

```
import com.project.ui.fragment.MyFragment_;
```

After that the following :

```
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment_();
```

works better, evidently.

Comment: But the fragment is not injected, it was declared, am I right ?